# How come my @media query doesn't work?

Tags: css, media-queries

```css
    * {
      background-color:grey;
    }
    body {
      margin: 0 ;
    }
    #container {
      height:800px;
      display:flex;
      
      text-align:center;
      
      justify-content:flex-start;
      flex-direction: column;
    }


  

    

    #container {
      width:15%;
    }

    #container > a {
      flex:1;
      border-radius:10px;
      height:100px;
    }

    #box-1 {
      background-color:green;
      
      flex-grow: 2;
       

    }
    #box-2 {
      background-color:yellow;
      
      
    }
    #box-3 {
      background-color:pink;
        
     
      
          }

    #box-4 {
      background-color:aqua;
      
     
      }

    #box-5 {
      background-color:blue;
      
     
    }

    #box-6 {
      
      background-color:chocolate;
     
    }


    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: olive;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
  <div id="container">
    <a id="box-1" href="#"></a>
    <a id ="box-2" href="#"></a>
    <a id="box-3" href="#"></a>
    <a id="box-4" href="#"></a>
    <a id="box-5" href="#"></a>
    <a id="box-6"href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
</nav>
</body>
```

Hello , recenly I was learning flexbox, and right now I'm trying to go back to @media rule and it doesn't seem to work. I even tried  changing it to w3 school's @media rule example . But it doesn't change its background-color to olive as it is written in the @media rule. Could anyone explain me how come it doesn't work?

Comment: Replace `* {background-color: grey}` with `body {background-color: grey}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `html` in your css like so:

```
html, body {
background-color: olive;
}
```

[Here's a working example](https://www.codeply.com/go/05Yd8U5Ahp)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is simply that, in the snippet in your question, `nav` takes up the entire page, so it completely covers `body`. The background color `body` will only show if there are not elements on top of it.

Nav is being affected by this rule:

```
* {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

The best thing to do is to not use the wildcard selector for setting background color. Instead, if you want the background of your page to be gray on desktop and olive on mobile, do that:

```
body {
  background-color: grey;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: olive;
 }
}
```

Then delete the wildcard rule entirely. Make a separate rule for the elements that you actually want to have a special background color as needed.

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 0;
}
#container {
  height: 800px;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#container {
  width: 15%;
}
#container>a {
  flex: 1;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 100px;
}
#box-1 {
  background-color: green;
  flex-grow: 2;
}
#box-2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
#box-3 {
  background-color: pink;
}
#box-4 {
  background-color: aqua;
}
#box-5 {
  background-color: blue;
}
#box-6 {
  background-color: chocolate;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: olive;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
    <div id="container">
      <a id="box-1" href="#"></a>
      <a id="box-2" href="#"></a>
      <a id="box-3" href="#"></a>
      <a id="box-4" href="#"></a>
      <a id="box-5" href="#"></a>
      <a id="box-6" href="#"></a>
      <a href="#"></a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
nav {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

The reason: `nav` is 100% wide and takes on the background color from the `*` rule, therefore its grey background spreads across the whole width, even below 600px width. The rule above prevents that and lets the olive background of `body` come through.

```css
* {
  background-color: grey;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  height: 800px;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
}

nav {
  background-color: transparent;
}

#container {
  width: 15%;
}

#container>a {
  flex: 1;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 100px;
}

#box-1 {
  background-color: green;
  flex-grow: 2;
}

#box-2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#box-3 {
  background-color: pink;
}

#box-4 {
  background-color: aqua;
}

#box-5 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#box-6 {
  background-color: chocolate;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: olive;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
    <div id="container">
      <a id="box-1" href="#"></a>
      <a id="box-2" href="#"></a>
      <a id="box-3" href="#"></a>
      <a id="box-4" href="#"></a>
      <a id="box-5" href="#"></a>
      <a id="box-6" href="#"></a>
      <a href="#"></a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```